# checkbox and submit button without any form element

Tags: html, django

I am trying to create a checkbox html element and a submit button. But my requirement is they should not be a part of a html form element.

Now I need to use these 2 elements inside a Django view.

Is there anyway I could achieve this . I am not sure how to access the not form elements inside django view.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want. What do you mean with "*shouldn't be part of a html form element*"?

Comment: @William. Normally we put input elements inside a form. So when post request happens we can access the form attributes. But if I just want a checkbox and a submit button without having them inside a form element,How do I access them inisde a django view.

Comment: Well that is exactly the purpose of a `<form>` to submit the values, otherwise those are not submitted. You can use JavaScript to later add the values to the form, but that would basically be awful design.